# Sum Product with two conditions and two arrays

Tags: excel, function

I have a system that lets you enter products onto a spreadsheet. Each product has a description, a suggested price, a quantity, and a price override. My code is:

```
=IF('Quantity'>0,SUMPRODUCT(--('Description Array'19:500 = 'Product Name'), 'Quantity Array'19:500, 'Price Override Array'19:500),0)
```

When they enter a Product Name, it will put the suggested price into the Price Override Array on the same row. Then this will find all products of the same name, and SUMPRODUCT their quantities and prices together to get our item cost.

The complex part is, I want to set it up so if the Price Override field is left blank, it defaults to our Suggested Price for that row. Is there a way to use SUMPRODUCT to do this?

Comment: That's a great idea! Why didn't I think of that haha.

Answer (score 0):

for the 2nd parameter of the IF statement point to a cell that has the default value instead of giving it a value of 0

Comment: I think a new IF statment inside the SUMPRODUCT statement will be necessary.

Comment: I thought about another IF statement, but SUMPRODUCT makes you input a range. I don't know how to isolate the cell that has a blank price.